# Unable to CREATE DATABASE postgresql on Heroku Hobby database

Tags: heroku-postgres

I connected to Heroku postgresql  DB (Hobby env):
heroku pg:psql --app

The prompt shows :
appname::DATABASE=>

**Error :**
appname::DATABASE=> CREATE DATABASE **hello** ENCODING 'UTF-8';

**ERROR:  permission denied to create database**

Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a database is disallowed because it's unnecessary. When you provision a Heroku Postgres add-on, the database and user are created on your behalf. You can see the information by running `heroku config` and checking the database configuration string.